# How to install shell commands in Atom to enable the atom command?

Tags: shell, atom-editor

Could someone please tell me how to install the shell commands for Atom to enable the `atom` command in the command line?

Comment: Thank you! How can I know whether the `apm` and `atom` have been installed in `Path`? Because when I checked `Path` I found no path where `apm` or `atom` is mentionned. Nevertheless, when I look up on my desktop, I can see that there is `.apm`.

Comment: I turned my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 9):

According to the Atom [Flight Manual](http://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/), they should be installed when you run Atom for the first time.

> When you first open Atom, it will try to install the `atom` and `apm` commands for use in the terminal. In some cases, Atom might not be able to install these commands because it needs an administrator password. To check if Atom was able to install the `atom` command, for example, open a terminal window and type `which atom`. If the `atom` command has been installed, you'll see something like this:
>
> ```
> $ which atom
> /usr/local/bin/atom
> $
> ```
>
> If the `atom` command wasn't installed, the `which` command won't return anything:
>
> ```
> $ which atom
> $
> ```
>
> To install the `atom` and `apm` commands, run "Window: Install Shell Commands" from the [Command Palette](http://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/atom-basics#command-palette), which will prompt you for an administrator password.

On my system (a Mac), they are installed in `/usr/local/bin`, but the location might vary depending on which platform you are using.

**EDIT**: I see your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40954643/2449905) where you indicate you're using Windows. So this may not apply to you, as the quoted section deals with Mac computers. But I'll leave the answer here in case it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Thank you Dan, when I type `which atom`, it does not return anything which basically means it is not installed yet. 

When I run the Command Palette, and type "Window: Install Shell Commands", it says "No matches found"..

Answer (score 5):

*I realize this is an old thread, but I felt I could help on this one as I did not see a lot of answers.*

I had the same problem of not being able to run `atom` from the CLI, on my Windows box.

My solution was to

1. completely uninstall both GIT for windows **and** Atom,
2. then reinstalling GIT bash first,
3. then during the installation I used the third option under the *"Adjusting your Path environment"* which was *"Use Git and optional Unix tools from the Windows Command Prompt"*.
4. After that I installed Atom.

So GIT and ATOM in that order. This added both Git and optional Unix tools to the PATH.

*The downside is having to reinstall all your packages which for me was not fun as I had way too many.*

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this?
https://atom.io/packages/atom-shell-commands

Im working with ubuntu and just went to the terminal and type:

$ sudo apm install atom-shell-commands

and then adding the commands to .config.cson file following the atom manual. Im newue with atom.