# What to add to `Path` in "System Variables" to install shell commands to enable the Atom command?

Tags: shell, path, atom-editor

I hope you are having a nice weekend. As I am under Windows, the `install shell commands` option is not available. As I tried to install shell commands to enable the atom command at the command line, I have to add something to the `Path` in "System variables". If someone has any idea on what I should put there, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to read this thread https://discuss.atom.io/t/opening-atom-via-window-command-prompt-in-current-folder/11026/14 especially jeancroy's May 25th posting that includes a bin path and a suggestion for a file to remove to fix this under Windows.