# How to install shell commands to enable the atom command at the command line?

Tags: shell, atom-editor

I have been stuck for two days looking for a solution. Could anybody please tell me how to install shell commands in Atom to enable the atom command at the command line under Windows. I know that it is not installed because when I typed `which atom`, it returns nothing.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to install inside the Atom editor a command which then starts another copy of the Atom editor?????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install shell commands in Atom to enable the atom command at the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946572/how-to-install-shell-commands-in-atom-to-enable-the-atom-command-at-the-command)

Comment: I will just delete it in a few. Unfortunately nobody was capable of helping me solve the problem on the website. However, I got helped somewhere else and I got `atom` installed through cmd.exe. 

Nonetheless, I would like to open an atom file on Bash but I have an error message. 

```$ atom README.md
/mnt/c/Users/ikine/AppData/Local/atom/bin/../app-1.12.6/resources/cli/atom.sh: line 9: pwd: -W: invalid option
pwd: usage: pwd [-LP]
'/atom.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

If you could help me,it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is you're asking the same question on two different threads, making it impossible to follow... A `man pwd` shows that pwd does not accept -W option. I don't understand why you have to use pwd to open a file in atom ?

Comment: I did not use pwd,it is weird. I just typed `$ atom README.md`.

Je te remercie !

Comment: When you open your file within Atom, with File>Open file, what's happening ?

Comment: It gives me a page called "untitled" where I can write code.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your other thread, I understand that you want to install a package who emulates shell commands *within* Atom. If so, you just have to follow the installation steps for Windows on Atom's website (I think you got confused with this `which` command story on the other thread, which explains how to install it on Linux and macOS).

I don't really know how to execute programs with command-line in Windows, if you don't master it either, I'd recommend using the graphics mode, and simply open your `README.md` file with the <kbd>FILE</kbd> button, like in any other software.

When you have Atom properly installed, there'll be some packages created to emule a terminal with shell commands, like [this one](https://atom.io/packages/atom-shell-commands). But this is independant from executing Atom from your computer. It emulates a terminal *within* Atom. I hope this is a little bit clearer.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Actually, I am following a book by Michael Hartl called 'Learnenough' and I have to follow the instructions otherwise I cannot move to the next chapter. That's why I have to solve this problem, because that's what he does on the screencast, it is just that he's working on Mac which makes tasks way easier for him.

Comment: I got it, you're following this guide : https://www.learnenough.com/text-editor-tutorial#sec-exercises_choosing. Indeed the author is on Unix and you're on Windows, so you must adapt his steps and not follow them blindly. Try to find what goal he's looking to reach behind every instruction. Here he's trying to install a shell command to open Atom from command line in Linux, but if you can launch your program by clicking on it on windows, you don't need this. You also need to install apm, you'll find instructions on the net for this. Always adapt the instructions to your situation.

Comment: Ah I see, I am in the 2.1 section, 2nd question to be accurate. I have no idea, I am just trying to learn. I have been taking his command line tutorial which seemed to work perfectly in bash, so I thought it was going to be the same in this tutorial. Vim as well worked fine, however in this section I got stuck for 3 days now.