# Coding Editors That Have a Command Window

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor

I am currently using DreamWeaver to write HTML, CSS, and Javascript code. I have discovered that Dreamweaver does not have a command window (e.g. the Command Window in Matlab) where I can test snippets of code and see the status/value/types of variables I am creating in my Javascript. Can I please get a list of about 3 or more free/low-cost editors that do have a command window? Live preview of the code would be great, too.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done some research yourself? Try using Visual Studio Code for example.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at Visual Studio. I just started looking last night. I have since look at atom, brackets, notepad++, but I cannot find a command window or the such in any of those. So, I am not sure how to search. I google "code editors with command line window". Is my wording incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also recommend vs code (visual studio code). [Illustration of command window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag0Zi.png). If you do choose it, make sure you download vscode and not visual studio.

Comment: Thanks for the preview of the command window. I am going to download it. Out of curiosity, do the other text editors I mentioned earlier not have a command window, or was I just not finding the command window in them? If there is no command window, then how do people write programs like Javascript without seeing their variable values or testing snippets? Thanks to both of you again.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the other editors to answer that, but i'd say a fairly good assumption is that they support it, or it would easily be able to be implemented through a plugin. If you're looking into Atom, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946572/how-to-install-shell-commands-in-atom-to-enable-the-atom-command