# Installing Shell Commands in Atom on macOS returns error and fails

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, atom-editor

I wanted to install shell commands on my MacBook Air 2017 (macOS: 10.15.3) in Atom. It asks for my root password and then returns an error in Atom:

```
Failed to install shell commands
mkdir failed with exit status 1
```

How do I fix this and install shell commands? 
When I try `which atom` in Terminal, it returns with `atom not found`

Comment: `mkdir will fail if the directory already exists` Are you sure if the directory you are creating already exists? What are you running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide more information? What command have you used (`mkdir`)? Is that directory already exists? Have you installed atom command?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946572/how-to-install-shell-commands-in-atom-to-enable-the-atom-command) might help you

Comment: I don’t know why it didn’t seem to work before, but I tried it again through the command palette this time and it said they have been already installed. And now using the ‘which atom’ command gives the correct response. Thank you.