# how to command atom from the terminal. I have tried atom . but it doesnt work

Tags: atom-editor, iterm2

-bash: atom: command not found

how can I fix this? I need to command atom from the terminal. How do I open atom from my terminal. It seems like the terminal can't locate atom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install shell commands in Atom to enable the atom command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946572/how-to-install-shell-commands-in-atom-to-enable-the-atom-command)

Comment: That implies you have not installed Atom.